# Have MacOS-like window animations on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: software-recommendation, themes, 19.04, alternative, animations

I'm looking, if possible, for a way to make Ubuntu 19.04's window animations a bit more similar or exactly the same as on Mac. (If possible, I'd like to keep my GNOME Desktop)

Desired look&feel : https://images.app.goo.gl/iFnJADgewUAfGSWv7

Comment: So you want the animations of Ubuntu on MacOS? That would be off-topic here.

Comment: Apologies for the ambiguous title, I wanted the MacOS animation on Ubuntu, not the other way around.

Comment: “Google brings me to Compiz” Please [edit] your question to _include_ the link. You should include _all_ relevant links, e.g. what you mean by “MacOS animation”.

Comment: Links added, please let me know should further clarification be needed.

Comment: I understood what you want. it seems the transition from xorg-Unity-compiz-metacity to Wayland-gnome-Mutter really slowed down ubuntu comunity getting ubuntu back to the same level of configurability it had. there is for example an ongoing effort to bring wobbly windows back but I think the plan is for minimization animations to be controlled with either other tools such as ubuntu-tweak or to be internal. Or most likely a gnome extension.

Comment: Ah I see. So is such customization not possible currently?

Comment: @tatsu - I guess wobbly windows is too much for what is asked. isn't the question just about the way windows are *minimized*?

Comment: What do you want to show with the image? The in/out of a minimized window?

Comment: @404NameNotFound yeah not quite yet. we'll get back there though. back in the day ubuntu was king of desktop customisations. and I won't lie it's probably what got a whole genration into linux as nerdy as that may sound today.

Comment: @cipricus At this point my main interest is just to get the animation, but I can't help notice the other customization posibilities, so I'm interested to see where that can take me. And yes, the image shown is the animation I want, a bit of Google shows me it was possible with the compiz manager.

Comment: @tatsu Well alright, thanks for the information.

Comment: @404NameNotFound I imagine this video is what brough you to ask this question : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sfsKwzElxQg if not you should really check it out. (18.04 tricks will work on 19.04)

Comment: @tatsu I followed a similar video, so I have everything close to that point. Just need the animations now.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same and finally found similar one, it's called 'Compiz like magic lamp'. link: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3740/compiz-alike-magic-lamp-effect/